# How to find which processes are taking all the memory?

Tags: process, memory, top

I'm looking for somthing like top is to CPU usage. Is there a command line argument for top that does this? Currently, my memory is so full that even 'man top' fails with out of memory :)

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/blog-post.html

Comment: Thanks @Vijay , that one also worked on Solaris 9 flawlessly.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

From inside `top` you can try the following:

- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
- Press the Letter corresponding to %MEM
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You might also try:

```
$ ps -eo pmem,pcpu,vsize,pid,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head -5
```

This will give the top 5 processes by memory usage.

Comment: Under Linux, simply press `M` to sort by physical memory usage (RES column). Under *BSD, run `top -o res` or `top -o size`. But [htop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-to-find-which-processes-are-taking-all-the-memory/5004#5004) is a lot nicer and doesn't even consume more memory than top (however it's not part of the basic toolset so you might not have it installed).

Comment: I had to press `s` to sort by `%MEM` and, then hit escape for top.

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris 9.

Comment: @Steven How can we group process with same parent? Basically firefox shows up in multiple times may be as it spawns multiple child processes. Is it possible to get combined memory usage?

Comment: `$ top`
> `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` - In case anyone else appreciates this

Answer (score 14):

If you have it installed I like `htop`  once launching it you can press <kbd>f6</kbd>, <kbd>down arrow</kbd> (to `MEM%`), <kbd>enter</kbd> to sort by memory.

Answer (score 8):

In Solaris the command you would need is:

```
prstat -a -s size
```

This will list all processes in order of descending process image size.  Note that the latter is based on memory committed to the process by the OS, not its resident physical memory usage.

There are supposedly versions of "top" available for Solaris, but these are not part of the standard installation.

Comment: Finally something that works on Solaris 9! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Once `top` starts, press <kbd>F</kbd> to switch to the sort field screen. Choose one of the fields listed by pressing the key listed on the left; you probably want <kbd>N</kbd> for `MEM%`

Comment: If you want MEM%, pressing 'M' does the same stated above. 'c' adds command line parameters to the process list, may be informative for your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris 9

Answer (score 6):

This command will identify the top memory consuming processes:

```
ps -A --sort -rss -o pid,pmem:40,cmd:500 | head -n 6 | tr -s " " ";z"
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris 9:
`ps: illegal option -- -
ps: ort is an invalid non-numeric argument for -s option
ps: illegal option -- r
ps: s is an invalid non-numeric argument for -s option
ps: unknown output format: -o pmem:40
ps: unknown output format: -o cmd:500`

Answer (score 5):

One nice alternative to `top` is `htop`. Check it, it is much more user friendly than regular top.

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved in multiple ways,
My favourite one is:

**The PS way:**

1. `[arif@arif ~]$ ps -eo pid,cmd,%cpu,%mem --sort=-%mem`

   Where,

   - `-e`: to select all process
   - `-o`: to apply to the output format
   - `pid`,`cmd`,`%cpu`,`%mem`: Output format in exact order. Here, `pcpu` and `pmem` can be used instead of `%cpu` and `%mem`.
   - But sadly (don't know why) **it doesn't work** on some machine (Oracle Linux) and some older machine. You can use the following similar alternatives.
2. `[arif@arif ~]$ ps aux --sort '-%mem' --cols 120 | head`

   Where,

   - `--cols 100`: to specify column width of the output as sometimes `cmd` gets very long. This is not necessary if you don't want curtailed commands with arguments.
   - `aux`: to see every process on the system using BSD syntax
3. `[arif@arif ~]$ ps -eo pid,cmd,%cpu,%mem --sort -rss`

   Where,

   - `-rss`: resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used
4. `[arif@arif ~]$ ps aux --sort -rss --cols 120`

**The top way**:

`[arif@arif ~]$ top -b -o +%MEM`

Where,

- `-b`: to use `top` as `batch` mode.
- `-o`: to override sort fieldname followed by a fieldname `%MEM`

And you can always use `head` and/or `tail` to control the output.

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris 9. The `top` cmd-lines gives: `top: '+%MEM' is not a recognized sorting order.
        Try one of these: cpu size res time
`

Answer (score 2):

**Globally:**
     It's always recommended to use a log analyser tool for logging history logs such as Splunk, ELK etc. So that using query language you can easily get the PIDs and its usage by CPU & memory.

**AT SERVER/OS  LEVEL:**
From inside top you can try the following:

```
 Press SHIFT+M  ---> This will give you a process which takes more memory in descending order.
```

You might also try:

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -10
```

This will give the top 10 processes by memory usage.
Also you can use vmstat utility to find the RAM usage at same time not for history.

Comment: Thanks, the `top` tip worked on Solaris 9. The `ps` cmd-line did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ps aux --sort -rss | head` or `ps aux | sort -nk +4 | tail`

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris 9

Answer (score 0):

This alias works nice for me in a **bash shell**:

```
alias mtop='{ echo "Mem% PID Binary"; ps -A --sort -rss -o pid,pmem:40,cmd:500 | tail -n +2 | head -n 10 | tr -s " " | sed -r "s/^\s*([0-9]+) ([0-9.]+) ([a-zA-Z/]+).*$/\2 \1 \3/"; } | column -t -s " "'
```

This will print out a neat list of processes sorted by memory consumption:

```
-=# mtop
Mem%  PID     Binary
22.9  528235  /opt/intellij
5.4   906569  /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java
3.7   544512  /usr/bin/node
2.2   986170  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
1.9   795138  /usr/bin/node
1.1   795188  /usr/bin/node
1.0   747819  /usr/lib/jvm/java
0.9   599     /usr/bin/pipewire
0.7   414     /usr/lib/Xorg
0.7   544536  /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, `ps` does not support the `--sort` option.

You can use the BSD-only `-m` flag to sort by "memory usage," which avoids piping all rows through `sort`. (The `ps` man page doesn't specify exactly which "memory usage" metric is used.)

```
ps -m -aexo pmem,rss,vsize,pid,etime,user,args | head
```

---

Or, if you want sorting by CPU: you can use the BSD-only `-r` flag to sort by cpu usage.

```
ps -r -aexo pcpu,cputime,pid,etime,user,args | head
```

Comment: The question is about memory, not CPU time.

Comment: @Ternvein good point, I copied the wrong snippet from my debugging notes ;) Added memory too now.